# How long does it take for a Firebase Hosting url to be available again after it was deleted?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a firebase hosting site, and I'm migrating it. So in order to be able to use the same URL in the new project, I deleted the site from the original project. But it is not available yet. Does anyone know how long it takes for this URL to be available again after I deleted it?

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm actually not sure. It might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, so that they can check with the engineering team (and possibly speed matters up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you're trying to move `<site>.web.app` or `<site>.firebaseapp.com` to a new project, unfortunately you can't. Site names are immutable and never free up once claimed, even if the project/site is deleted.

Custom domains can be removed from one site and added to another immediately, but shared domains are not recycled.